# floats decimals comparison cocos2d

Tags: timer, cocos2d-iphone

Hello people here is my problem:
How i reduce a float number with only to decimals? %.1 is best for me but when i compare with another float like unNumero= 1.7f the code dont do it. I think because the float have more numbers. How can i solve this. I need to compare the result of the stopCrono with some random floats but limit with 2 decimals. Sorry my english is not my native language.
Here is my code

-(void)startCrono:(ccTime)delta {

```
totalTime += delta  ;
currentTime = totalTime;
timeLimit = 2.0f;
[timeLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f ",currentTime ]];
if (currentTime >= timeLimit) {

    [self unschedule:_cmd];
    }
```

}
-(void)stopCrono:(ccTime)crono2{

```
[self unschedule:@selector(startCrono:)];
unNumero = 1.7f;

if(unNumero == currentTime){

    CCLOG(@"OK");
}
```

}

The if staetment is not working CClog not print OK when i stop my crono in 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because floating-point math is not exact, comparing two floating-point values to see if they are equal with the == operator does not usually yield the result you would expect. I recommend you [this article](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) by Bruce Dawson, which is part of an excellent series on floating-point numbers, to understand how to compare floating-point values in a proper way (hint: it is much harder than what it looks like).